# Why doesn't asp.net css link path work outside of the head tag?

Tags: asp.net

Why doesn't asp.net css link path work outside of the head tag?

I have this code in a master page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="../CSS/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

This seems to resolve the CSS link no mater what folder depth the page is at.

I notice that if you use the css link it only resolves to the correct path if it's in the head (if used in the body it does not work).

I know how to get around it by using ResolveUrl, but I am wondering if this is just how it works or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET does some magic rebasing of urls in link and script tags when you specify runat="server" on the head element of a master page.

There are some details of this strange behavior [here](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/more_on_url_rebasing_in_master_pages.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like this is just how it is.  That is very strange.  I wonder why they didn't create an asp:link server control that can take a relative path like the asp:image and asp:HyperLink does.

Comment: @webdtc They did. System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink. It gets instantiated when you do <link runat="server"/>

Comment: @webdtc That's what makes the behavior even more strange. The HtmlHead control of the same namespace is sensitive to its literal content, which is not typical of other controls.

Comment: My link is runat server and it does not resolve the url.

I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink(VS.80).aspx perhaps if I do it that way it will work the way I expected it to?

Answer (score 1):

Server controls will process relative URLs and will output the appropriate URL to the client. `<head runat='server'>` is a server control that does this. If you remove the `runat='server'` attribute, you'll see that this address translation won't happen anymore.